# My header have 768px as my menu but my menu appears smaller?

Tags: html, css

I'm getting mad with a problem that I'm having that I really cant understand what is happening.

I have a #topo section with 768px of with.

And then I have a menu div with 768px of with.

The logo is that yellow div in my image, The menu is the gray div in my image.

Can you understand why they have the same with, but in my page, as you see in my image they have different with and then my page appears with the scroll bar to go right????

[image]

**I have this jsffidle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ra3zc/10/

(but in jsfiddle happens t he opposite, my menu appears smaller then my div "topo")

My html:

```
<header id="topo">
    <span id="logo">
        <a href="index.php" style="margin-left:350px;">LOGO</a>
    </span>
</header>

<section id="menu-container">
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>    
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li style="border-top:none;"><a href="#">Link 1.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1.2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li> 
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li style="border-top:none;"><a href="#">Link 2.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2.2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li> 
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li style="border-top:none;"><a href="#">Link 3.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3.2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li> 
        </ul>
    </nav>  
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `#menu` in fact does not have `background:gray`, it's your `#menu-container` which has width of 100%. So just apply `background:gray` to your `#menu` instead of `#menu-container` and you will have the expected result:

```
#menu {
  background:gray;
}
```

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/ra3zc/13/)

For the visibility of the vertical scrollbar. When you set `ul`'s width to `768px`, its **total width** in fact is not just `768px`, the total width is added with the default padding making it overflow the container and hence your problem. The default `box-sizing` of your `ul` is `content-box`, that means setting `width:768px` will set the width of the **content**, then the total width will be that width plus the default padding. So you can have some following solutions:

```
/* set overflow:hidden on the parent #menu */
#menu {
   ...
   overflow:hidden;
}
/* set padding of your ul to 0 */
#menu ul {
   ...
   width: 768px;
   padding:0;
}
/* set box-sizing of your ul to border-box */
#menu ul {
   ...
   width: 768px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
}
/* The last solution is don't set the width for your ul */
#menu ul {
   ...
   /*width: 768px; */
}
```

**NOTE**: You don't need to set the `width` for your `ul`, it will fill the `#menu` container automatically. While you already set the `width:768px` for the parent `#menu`.

Comment: Thank you the background problem was really that the problem. But the main problem its not that because I continue having my scroll bar to go right, like if there is something bigger that all other things

Comment: @OzzC updated the fiddle, it's because you set `768px` for the height of the `ul`

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/ra3zc/12/)**</kbd>

As King King said, also add `margin-top:0;` to `#menu ul` to get the desired result.

```
#menu {
  background:gray;
}

#menu ul {
  margin-top:0;
}

#menu-container {
  background:gray /* remove this from #menu-container */
}
```

For your other issues

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/ra3zc/14/)**</kbd>

Add `max-width: 768px` and `width:100%;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think I explain mysefl bad. The problem is that I have a media querie for 768px, and I have all elements with width of 768px, and I dont understand why, my scrooll bar always appears, and I can go more right, do you understand? Because if all elements have the same with (768px) that is the with of the page why still appears the bottom scroll bar?

Comment: @OzzC have you checked out my fiddle? The explanation is not clear?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/ra3zc/15/       
remove style="margin-left:350px;" inline style..

Comment: I am not able to understand whats the problem is? can you post a screenshot or some more codes?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="wrapper">
head element
body element
<div>


#wrapper {
width: 768px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If you want them in the same size, you should use wrapper, then it will be in the same line.